# 1 GB Data with key and value, what kind of data structure to store them? 1TB? 1 PB?

Tags: data-structures, bigdata

There is 1 GB data with key and value, what kind of data structure to store them? If data increase to 1TB? 1 PB? You need to access them frequently every day. And how long you need to access them? What about true time? One minute? One hour?

I answered like using `hashtable` in 1GB and 1TB. A few seconds to take? I'm not sure how to calculate the true time. When coming to 1 PB, we can sort the data and divide them into several part and store them in `hashtables`.

Seems the interviewer are not satisfied with the answer. Seems I'm totally wrong :(

Comment: You can't store structures that large in memory. Memory in modern (desktop or laptop) computers is usually in the 1-8 GB range- 1TB would be completely out of the question in all but very specialized systems. You need a database (SQL, for example) that stores it on disk.

Comment: For instance, try using your favorite language to create a hash table with a few million key/value pairs, where each value is (say) a 1kb string. You'll crash your computer pretty quickly. This is why databases are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the choice of structure depends heavily on how much memory you have. But RAM is totally out of the question when you say 1TB or 1PB. When interviewers ask questions like these, they are actually trying to see how good you are at logical thinking rather than expecting some spot-on, exact solution(At least I feel this).

Coming back to your actual question, you could use some distributed  platform, like Hadoop, as Sreejith has said. In systems like Hadoop you use multiple systems together as a single system in order to leverage their combined power to gain better performance. With an approach like this you can significantly reduce the read/write time as compared to a single machine, even if it is very powerful with very good RAM and processor. Along with this Hadoop also provides data structures like [SequenceFile](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile) which makes it very easy to store and process huge datasets.

But whatever method you choose, disk based access(which cannot be avoided when dealing with data of ~TB or ~PB) will always be slower than memory based access. So, you need to choose some data structure which allows you to minimize disk accesses as much as possible. See this [paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~matias/papers/synopsis-soda99.pdf) for a detailed info on what i'm trying to say.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

For data in TBs and PBs best solution is Hadoop. Go with Hbase and hadoop. Hbase is same like Google table which perfroms on key value pair  which is build on top of hadoop. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. So is "Hadoop" the best answer to this question?